# How to avoid/stop webpage flickering with python selenium firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox

I am trying to scrape a webpage to download some images. For this I need to:

- get image elements
- loop through them and download each one, where download means:

  - right-click
  - press download button
- scroll down the page to get new elements

However, after some hundreds iterations I occasionally have a weird behaviour when the next element is at the very beginning of the page. In fact, when I click on the element with `image.click()`, the driver starts flickering. This of course breaks the next processing with actions to right-click and download.

Apologies in advance for the few details. Unfortunately I am not able to share reproducible code/examples since the repository is accessible only through my credentials.
I try to attach the code I am using and a gif to visualize the problem.
As you can see, the webpage is static at first (bottom), then when I run `image.click()` (top) the webpage starts flickering (bottom).

```
driver.get(website_url)

SLEEP_START = 3
SLEEP_LOAD = 0.3

time.sleep(SLEEP_START)
folder_element = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, '//div[@class="material-list-line-1" and text()="INFN_New"]'
)


action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.double_click(folder_element).perform()

time.sleep(SLEEP_START)

action = ActionChains(driver)


def download_image(image, chain_sleep=0):
    # right click and download
    try:
        action.context_click(image).pause(chain_sleep).send_keys(Keys.TAB).pause(
            chain_sleep
        ).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP).pause(chain_sleep).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
    except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException as e:
        print("Catched OOB exception at:", image.text)
        print("\n\n", e)


def download_current_images(images, chain_sleep=0):
    downloaded = []
    for i, image in enumerate(tqdm(images), start=1):
        if image.text == "RT366S1C3R1_r1.JPG":
            print("Here we go ...") # breakpoint here, since it starts flickering
            image.click()
        if a:
            print("Yes, I am starting from the right place")
            raise (NotImplementedError())

        # scrolling every 10 files
        if (i % 10) == 0:
            # print('Scrolling at', image.text)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", image)
            time.sleep(SLEEP_LOAD)
        try:
            image.click()
        except ElementClickInterceptedException as e:
            print("Catched click exception at:", image.text)
            print("\n\n", e)

            try:
                # CASE 1: opened preview -> roll back to list view, then run delayed
                close_preview_button = driver.find_element(
                    By.XPATH,
                    "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button/div/span",
                )
                time.sleep(5)
                close_preview_button.click()
                image = images[i - 2]
                image.click()
                download_image(image, chain_sleep=0.5)
                print("correctly downloaded", image.text)
                print("see if I continue from right place to avoid double download")
                a = 1
                continue

            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                # CASE 2: element out of bounds -> scroll first then click
                # print('It is not a problem of preview...')
                # print('Try scrolling instead at:', image.text)
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", image)
                time.sleep(SLEEP_LOAD)
                image.click()
        # download_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/span/div/div/div/div[1]/span/div/div/div")
        download_image(image)


        downloaded.append(image.text)
    return downloaded


def _get_new_image_elements(already_downloaded: list):
    icons = driver.find_elements(
        By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "material-list-line")]'
    )
    # only images
    image_elements = [icon for icon in icons if (icon.text.endswith("JPG"))]
    # only new elements
    image_elements = [
        image for image in image_elements if (image.text not in already_downloaded)
    ]
    return image_elements


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # get image elements of the first page
    page_elements = _get_new_image_elements(already_downloaded=[])

    # download
    print("downloading", len(page_elements), "images")
    downloaded_image_names = download_current_images(page_elements)

    # scroll
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", page_elements[-1])
    time.sleep(SLEEP_LOAD)

    # get new image elements and their names
    new_page_elements = _get_new_image_elements(downloaded_image_names)
    check_names = [*map(lambda x: x.text, new_page_elements)]

    # only run until new images are available
    while set(check_names).difference(downloaded_image_names) != set():
        # download new images
        print("downloading", len(new_page_elements), "images")
        new_downloads = download_current_images(new_page_elements)

        downloaded_image_names = downloaded_image_names + new_downloads
        time.sleep(SLEEP_LOAD)

        # scroll
        new_page_elements[-1].click()
        # time.sleep(SLEEP_LOAD)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", new_page_elements[-1])
        time.sleep(SLEEP_LOAD)

        # update image elements
        new_page_elements = _get_new_image_elements(downloaded_image_names)
        check_names = [*map(lambda x: x.text, new_page_elements)]
```

Any idea how to solve this? I'd be happy also to receive just hints about why this happens or what steps I may try to debug it :) [image]

Comment: Just a few suggestion
Try to add driver.implicitly_wait() to give the elements enough time to load before interacting with them.
you can also Check if the page has finished loading before interacting with the elements. You can use document.readyState to verify if the page is in a complete state.